# How to call Alarm intent using CountDownTimer constructor?

Tags: java, android, alarm

I am trying to set the alarm using CountDownTimer. I have time in milliseconds. How to achieve it?

Any Help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: Elaborated:
 I am trying to set alarm for added event in calendar. When the time is reached, the notification is shown. But i also have to set alarm that rings during notification of that event when shown.

Comment: still not getting your problem

Comment: Im trying to use countDownTimer constructor to set alarm through intent in my device. Refer my code at: http://pastebin.com/2ASA7Qgw

Comment: I m not getting the alarm sound or notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

                public void onFinish() {
    }};cntr_aCounter.start();
```

**here i have 30 second countdown are set. you can go ahead by this way.**

Comment: In onFinish method, i have to call alarm intent